# How do I prove this integral equality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $s\geq d\geq 1$ and $A$ be a $d\times s$ real matrix with integer entries and rank $d$. Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}^d$.

Then, how do I prove the following?

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^s}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^s} e^{i \langle k,At\rangle} dt = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^d} e^{i \langle k,t\rangle} dt $$?

Comment: Something's off. The right-hand side doesn't depend on $A$.

Comment: @StefanLafon No, this is true. I figured out how to prove this.. Since $rank(A^t)=rank(A)=d$, $A^tk=0$ implies $k=0$. Along with this and the fact that $\int e^{int} dt = \delta_{n,0}$, the above can be proven.